# How to create and join a channel correctly in hyper ledger fabric using python

Tags: python, command-line, hyperledger-fabric

Hello I am working on a thesis project based on block chain tech. I am developing using Hyperledger fabric python language.

```
based on this documentation : https://fabric-sdk-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html
```

Basically i have been able to :

1. start my fabric network
2. Create connection profile
3. start ca instance  server
4. Create users
5. revoke users based on certificates

Now I am trying to create a channel and join this channel, but i keep falling into an error as below

```
configtxgen not in path configtxgen empty
```

[A part of error in screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ntz1K.png)

[concluding part of screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ms7S4.png)

The error above points to the fact that configtx.yaml is not found

What i have tried to solve this?

I have tried setting the path of FABRIC_CFG_PATH to environment as below

```
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=Users/*******/Documents/hyper/fabric-sdk-py/fabric-samples/bin:$PATH


export FABRIC_CFG_PATH="$HOME/documents/hyper/fabric-sdk-py/fabric-samples/bin:$PATH"

export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$HOME/documents/hyper/fabric-sdk-py/test/fixtures/e2e_cli/:$PATH

export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=/home/**********/documents/hyper/fabric-sdk-py/test/fixtures/e2e_cli/$PATH
```

I am still unable to fix this, i need help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the documentation, you need configtxgen tool in your $PATH. `configtxgen` is coming as part of the fabric binaries bundle. You can get the binaries bundle for your fabric version [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases)(Download compatible version for your platform from the 'Assests' section). Download and extract the bundle and move `configtxgen` binary inside it to some location in your $PATH. You can verify whether `configtxgen` is accessible from terminal using

```
configtxgen -version
```

Comment: thank you so much, i will try this instruction and get back to u

Comment: Hello just to be sure, my FAB version is 1.4.6 which is the default used in the above tutorial. this is the corresponding asset link https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases?page=3  but i dont see any link for mac. I can see darwin, windows, linux and other source codes. which do i use, i make use of a mac . Thanks @Basil K Y

Comment: Hello i have been able to run the "configtxgen -version" command and  that works now. but then i try to join my channel again i still get same error please what can i do